# Counter example of the dominated convergence theorem, if the dominating function was not integrable.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f_1, f_2, f_3,\dots:\Omega \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be measurable functions such that
$$f_n \to f\quad f_n\geq f_{n+1}\geq 0$$
Show that if $f_1$ is integrable then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\Omega f_n \;d\mu = \int_\Omega f \;d\mu$$
Show also that if $f_1$ is not integrable, this equality need not be true.

---

The result follows immediately from the Dominated Convergence Theorem, if we use $f_1$ as the dominating function.

The counterexample is a bit harder. Consider $\Omega = \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $f:\overline{\mathbb{R}}\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and we have a measure space equipped with the Borel sigma-algebra and Lebesgue measure.

Let $$f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n}$$

Then $$f_n(x)\to f(x)=0\quad as \quad n\to\infty$$

But

$$\int_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}f_1 \;dm = \int_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}x \;dm = \infty\neq 0 = \int_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}f \;dm$$

Does this solution make sense to you?

Comment: None of the $f_n$'s is integrable on $\mathbb R$. So technically, writing $\int f_1 = \infty$ is an error. Just make the domain smaller...

Comment: @user251257 Can you explain further. Isn't the definition on nonintegrable that $\int f_1 = \infty$?

Comment: no, because $\int x^+ = \infty$ and $\int x^- = \infty$. So $\int x^+ - \int x^-$ isn't defined (and not $\infty$).

Comment: @user251257 Thanks I understand now. So I could just used $[0,\infty]$ as the domain and then $\int x^+ = \infty$ and $\int x^{-} = 0$

Comment: Yepp. Something like that.

Comment: You could also use an indicator function of $(n,\infty)$ as your counterexample.